# Can't declare unused exception variable when using catch-all pattern

Tags: c#, try-catch

what is a best practice in cases such as this one:

```
try
{
   // do something
}
catch (SpecificException ex)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/InformUserAboutAn/InternalException/");
}
```

the *warning* i get is that `ex` is **never used**.

however all i need here is to inform the user, so i don't have a need for it.

do i just do:

```
try
{
   // do something
}
catch
{
    Response.Redirect("~/InformUserAboutAn/InternalException/");
}
```

somehow i don't like that, seems strange!!? any tips? best practices?

what would be the way to handle this.

**thnx**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just don't declare the variable:

```
try
{
   // do something
}
catch (SpecificException)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/InformUserAboutAn/InternalException/");
}
```

This is a moot point when catching `System.Exception` (in your original example, which is not exactly the same as an empty `catch` -- [an empty `catch` will also catch COM exceptions](http://leedumond.com/blog/friends-dont-let-friends-catch-exception/), for instance), but this is the correct construct to use.

If you run your code through other analysis engines (Gendarme, for instance), you will also be warned that catching a plain `Exception` is poor practice because it can mask other exceptions besides what you really wanted to catch.  That's bitten me a few times while maintaining legacy code -- we were catching and ignoring an `Exception` on a file delete (or something like that), but the main logic wasn't working correctly.  We should have been only catching an `IOException`, but we were catching and discarding the `NullReferenceException` that was causing the failure.

That's not to say you *never* should catch `Exception`; just rarely.

Comment: i see, thnx. i updated the question with a Specific Exception. that was my bad in explaining it.

Comment: There is not need to declare use `catch (Exception)` if System.Exception is used. This syntax is needed when some other type is been catching, i.e. `catch (NullReferenceException)`

Comment: @b0x0rz: Yeah, if you need to address a specific exception, this is the way to go....still seems like an odd thing to do.  This is something you could (in theory) do in the global exception handler as well.  Just beware the pokemon.

Comment: `catch (Exception)` and `catch` are different.

Comment: @John: I was not aware of that.  I changed the answer slightly and put a link to an article explaining the difference.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jonh: And what is the different if `System.Exception` is used?

Comment: catch by const reference. Thus you prevent the system from copying the exception back from its special hidden place (also prevents slicing)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need Exception's variable to get some information from it, don't declare it

```
try { }
catch ( )
```

is equal to

```
try { }
catch (Exception) { }
```

Use this

```
try { }
catch (Exception ex) { var m = ex.Message; }
```

if you need some information to gather.

Use this

```
try { }
catch (FooException) { }
catch (BarException) { }
```

if you need to catch only specific types of exceptions, i.e. `SomeAnotherException` will not be caught.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you just let the exception bubble all the way up and use an application wide exception handler or something like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).  Usually you'll want to log the exception or something so there's a record of stuff failing.

Comment: yeah, but that is only for 'unhandled' exceptions it seems. i am handling this one. don't need reporting or anything. perhaps i can update the question with a SPECIFIC exception not any.

Comment: i do like the ELMAH though so great TIP ;)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you wouldn't let unhandled exceptions simply throw and use the Application Level error handling built into ASP.NET?  See [How to: Handle Application-Level Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I usually declare it and suffer with the warning since it can be very useful to be able to look at the exception details while debugging.

Comment: You can use Locals window during debug to check out automatically declared variable `$exception`. It's also available in Immediate window.

Answer (score -1):

There are two reasons to declare an exception variable in a catch block.  To catch only specific exception types or to do something with the exception info.  In your case you are doing neither so t serves no purpose.